# Dimensions of hist3 output

Tags: matlab, histogram, edges

I have this code:

```
a = [1 1 1 3 3 5];
b = [1 3 3 3 5 5];
edges{1} = [0 2 4 6];
edges{2} = [0 2 4 6];
edges = edges';
h = hist3([a' b'],'Edges',edges)
```

The output h is 4x4 matrix,

```
 1     2     0     0
 0     1     1     0
 0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0
```

However I think it should have been 3x3 since I have 4 entries for the edges, i.e
0-2,
2-4,
4-6

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The definition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html) of the `edge` handle in `hist3` is :

```
 edges{1}(i) <= X(k,1) < edges{1}(i+1)
```

So in your case:

```
 0<= x <2,
 2<= x <4,
 4<= x <6,
 6<= x
```

Because it has the `<=` logic, the last (4th) part of the histogram are for values that **exactly** equal `6`.

If you dont like it you can just delete the last row \ column of `h`

```
h(:,end)=[];
h(end,:)=[];
```

Comment: I tried creating a histogram again with a = [1 1 1 3 3 7]; It resulted in   
     [1     2     0     0;
     0     1     1     0;
     0     0     0     0;
     0     0     0     0]
So I think there is still something wrong

Comment: because there's no limit beyond `6`, the `<=6` is actually `=6`, this is also what I wrote in my answer "exactly equal 6"...

Comment: @natan According to Mathworks' definition, the last edge should be `x>=6`, why did you change it to equal to `(=)`? I realized that they (Mathworks) tell you to include +Inf and -Inf, but they also write `edges{1}(i) <= X(k,1) < edges{1}(i+1)`. Isn't it confusing?

Comment: @natan Also, with this logic, the last row and column are always going to be zero (unless you have values exactly equal to). What would have been the harm if they had kept it `>=` instead of exactly equal to?